# Why does lxadmin insecurely require me to type my root password in clear text to reboot my VPS machine?

Tags: security

In order to reboot my VPS, lxadmin requires me to type in my **root password in clear text**.

Is this a security oversight or am I missing something?

Comment: Is this over HTTPS? I'd want them to add 'autocomplete="off"' to the form field, but if it's HTTPS this isn't a huge issue.

Comment: Yes, it's over https, but why not just put in type="password" so that people standing around (or watching on remote connection) don't see you type in the root password (!).

Comment: [Administration panels are off topic](http://serverfault.com/help/on-topic). [Even the presence of an administration panel on a system,](http://meta.serverfault.com/q/6538/118258) because they [take over the systems in strange and non-standard ways, making it difficult or even impossible for actual system administrators to manage the servers normally](http://meta.serverfault.com/a/3924/118258), and tend to indicate low-quality questions from *users* with insufficient knowledge for this site.

Answer (score 1):

Probably a known issue.

http://www.milw0rm.com/exploits/8880

Not a lot of point reporting it

http://www.itwire.com/content/view/25559/53/

Answer (score 0):

> Is this a security oversight or am I
>   missing something?

It looks like a security oversight to me.  File a bug or complain.  Since you are probably not rebooting very often you probably don't have to hit that page very often, so the risk seems minimal.  On the other hand, that does make me wonder what other silly security related things they have done.